# Jenkins in Docker with custom path with nginx as a reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, jenkins, reverse-proxy

I want to deploy Jenkins in a Docker container. I will deploy other other containers with other software on the same port as Jenkins. Thus I used nginx as a reverse proxy and expose Jenkins container under path `/jenkins`.

My Docker Compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  reverseproxy:
    build: reverseproxy
    ports:
    - "8080:80"

  jenkins:
    image: jenkins:2.60.3
    volumes:
    - "./storage/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home"
    environment:
    - JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins"
```

My `reverseproxy` image:

```
FROM nginx:1.13.8-alpine                                                         

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

My `nginx.conf`

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream docker-jenkins {
        server jenkins:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location /jenkins/ {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-jenkins;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Docker Compose boots just fine. And I can access Jenkins on `http://localhost:8080/jenkins`. But as soon as I am trying to log in or log out, I am redirected to `http://localhost/jenkins/` (notice port is gone).

Here is `curl` output:

```
> curl -v localhost:8080/jenkins
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /jenkins HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.13.8
< Date: Mon, 08 Jan 2018 14:03:15 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 185
< Location: http://localhost/jenkins/
< Connection: keep-alive
<
```

Why am I redirected to `http://localhost/jenkins` without a port? Is something is wrong with the nginx configuration?

Comment: have you tried adding `listen 8080;` to your nginx `server` configuration? I read that nginx might have trouble with the Docker port mapping `8080:80` and you need to configure it to listen to both ports.